# interactjs "hold" sensitivity

Tags: javascript, ios, user-interaction

Using [interactjs](http://interactjs.io/), is there any way to control the sensitivity of drag v hold?  On PC getting the hold event to fire is quite easy with mouse.  On iPad/iPhone screen sensitivity (mostly finger pressure changes) make it quite hard to get the "hold" notification.  It's almost always a "drag".

There's [a repo fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/RobinsonUK/jvLakv8q/4/).

Code for interact is as follows:

```
interact('.draggable')
    .draggable(
        {
            inertia: false,
        }
    )
    .on('dragmove', function(event) 
    {                       
        event.preventDefault();

        var label = document.getElementById("label");

        if(label)
        {
            label.innerHTML = "DRAG";
        }        
    })
    .on('tap', function(event) {                
        event.preventDefault();

        var label = document.getElementById("label");

        if(label)
        {
            label.innerHTML = "TAP";
        }        
    })
    .on('down', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var label = document.getElementById("label");

        if(label)
        {
            label.innerHTML = "DOWN";
        }
    })
    .on('hold', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var label = document.getElementById("label");

        if(label)
        {
            label.innerHTML = "HOLD";
        }
    })
    .on('up', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var label = document.getElementById("label");

        if(label)
        {
            label.innerHTML = "UP";
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interact.pointerMoveTolerance( distance );
```

where `distance` is the distance in pixels that the pointer can move after being pressed down without a move/action happening.

You can see the effect by adjusting the slider in [this demo](https://rawgit.com/taye/interact.js/master/demo/events.html)

Comment: I initially misinterpreted the question and gave an incorrect answer. I've corrected it now.